# PHP7 não Funciona com SQL Server 2014

Tags: php, sql-server, php-7

Tenho um projeto funcionando no Xampp com PHP 5.6 e SQL Server 2014 Express.
Estou tentando migrar o projeto para PHP 7.1.0 mas está dando erro conforme imagem abaixo.

[image: Erro PHP 7]

Eu copiei as dll para a pasta ext do PHP que está em c:\php7\ext.
As quatro dll estão apresentando o erro abaixo.
Estou usando Apache 2.4.23 e o PHP 7.1.0.

```
extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts.dll
```

Comment: Instalou o Microsoft Drivers 4.0 for PHP for SQL Server?

Comment: Entre aspas. O instalar é um arquivo compactado.

Comment: O que é feito é descompactar dll na pasta ext e fazer o php.ini enxergar essas dll.

Comment: Isso mesmo; extrair no diretório de extensões o conteúdo de SQLSRV40.EXE.

Comment: Blz. Mas pq não funciona? Vc tem alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As DLLs de extensões do PHP são compiladas para funcionar em uma única versão do PHP. A DLL do PHP 5.6 irá travar no PHP 7, e a do PHP 7 também vai travar no PHP 7.1. Então, num primeiro momento, garanta que esteja utilizando **somente** a versão correta na pasta de `ext` e no `php.ini`

Se atente também que o PHP é compilado de [duas formas no Windows](http://windows.php.net/download#php-7.1): **thread safe** e **non thread safe**. Isso também influencia em qual extensão você deve usar.

A partir do PHP 7 também temos uma compilação para x64 e outra para x86. De novo, é preciso escolher a versão correta aqui também.

Supondo que você está usando a versão **Thread Safe** (a que vem junto com o XAMPP/Apache geralmente), baixe a extensão mais recente para trabalhar com o SQL Server. A forma mais fácil é olhar no [repositório do GitHub do driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/), na parte de releases e baixar somente a versão que você deseja.

Hoje o suporte para PHP 7.1 ainda está em preview, e a versão mais recente [é essa](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/4.1.4-Windows).

Baixe somente o zip para o PHP 7.1, escolha a arquitetura, thread safe ou não e extraia somente eles na pasta `ext` e insira no `php.ini`.

```
// suporte PDO
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
// sem PDO
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
```

Por fim, se não der certo, pode ser preciso atualizar também o [Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420). O SQL Server Express 2014 usa a versão 11 desse driver para conexão, e pelo que me lembre não sei se a nova versão do driver para PHP precisa que você atualize o ODBC também.

Comment: Eu renomeei a pasta do meu php de php7 para php7.1
Baixei a versão 7.0.14 e segui o passo-a-passo acima que eu já tinha feito quase tudo. A unica coisa que eu não tinha feito é atualizar o driver do meu obdc.  
Eu fiz downgrade da versão do php pq provavelmente as dll que eu estava utilizando, são para php 7.0.
http://c92021ba.ngrok.io/teste.php

Comment: Olha o meu phpinfo nesse link.

Comment: fabricio, no seu caso tenta essa versão aqui com [pdo](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/download/v4.0-RTW/php_pdo_sqlsrv_4.0.6_x64.zip) ou [sem pdo](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/download/v4.0-RTW/php_sqlsrv_4.0.6_x64.zip). Escolha com TS e tente atualizar o ODBC.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/fumRX
O mais estranho que dessa vez eu não estou conseguindo habilitar nem o pdo do mysql.
Vou fazer o que vc acaba de me pedir.

Comment: Olha essa imagem. http://imgur.com/a/q8han Está apontando para o c:\php e o correto é c:\php7\
Varios lugares estão pegando c:\php\ como padrão.

Comment: O caminho no apache estava errado.
Funcionou. Adeus xampp. Muito Obrigado.