# Extensão SQL Server não encontrada

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou tentando criar uma conexão com o SQLServer através do PHP 7.2 NTS, e mesmo tentando todas as combinações possíveis das DDL's não estou conseguindo sequer subir o servidor embutido.

minha configuração é a seguinte:

```
->Win10 x64 / PHP 7.2.13;
->Configuração de acesso à DLL:
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts_x64.dll
```

Estou usando o servidor embutido do PHP.

Ao tentar executar qualquer aplicação, e mesmo o `php --version` a seguinte mensagem é apresentada na console:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'php_sqlsrv_72_nts_x64.dll' (tried:
>   F:php\ext\php_sqlsrv_72_nts_x64.dll (Não foi possível encontrar o
>   módulo especificado.), F:php\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_72_nts_x64.dll.dll
>   (Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.)) in Unknown on
>   line 0

Comment: Pode apontar de onde você baixou essas dlls?

Comment: Talvez essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/171852/45810) te ajude...

Comment: baixei do site da microsoft.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017